.Net 8 Publish configuration - Trying to add the IIS requestFiltering option to our pubxml
We recently came across an issue where a specific front end feature was blocking file uploads, where the file was greater than 30MB (Angular front end, and .Net 8 API).
In the past we had the web.config, but the current approach is appsettings.json.
In the older web.config, we had the following requestLimits property:
<system.webServer>
 <security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
     </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>

which can NO LONGER be added to appsettings.json in .Net 8 projects.
So, the question is: how can we build this requestFiltering section into the web.config at Publish time.
Here is an example of FolderProfile.pubxml in our project:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release\net8.0-windows8.0\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>



Is this something that can be somehow injected into the web.config at build time or publish time ?

You might get some ideas from importing the publish settings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-iis?view=vs-2022

You can modify your .csproj file to include a custom MSBuild target that will append the necessary XML into the web.config file at the time of publishing.

we first tried creating the web.FolderProfile.config file, with only the necessary lines re: the IIS requestFiltering. We were hoping the VS Publish would merge those lines into the main web.config, but it did NOT. So as per Juan's answer below, we just added a web.config file to our project level. The Publish did indeed include those lines we added. We'll confirm everything at the next build.

Try placing the web.config with only the needed lines in your project.

Your suggestion appears to work. After Publishing the project, those lines re: IIS requestFiltering are in the published web.config.
